# Appendix Problem

Tags: appendices

I have a problem with \appendix in my thesis. 
The result it's correct in the ToC, 
[image: ToCappendix]

but wrong (i would like to have it as "Appendix A") in the text:

[image: textappendix]

I'm using this template: http://bror.einarsson.net/chalmersthesistemplate/ThesisTemplate.zip.

I think that the problem is in the settings:

```
% Chapter headings style (fncychap)
\makeatletter
\ChNumVar{} % sets the style for digit
\ChTitleVar{\Huge\bfseries\centering} % sets the style for title
\ChRuleWidth{4pt} % Set RW=4pt
\ChNameUpperCase % Make name uppercase
\renewcommand{\DOCH}{
\centering
{\CNoV {\fontsize{60pt}{20pt}\selectfont\thechapter} }
\vskip 40\p@}
\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@}
\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@}
\makeatother
```

I will really appreciate your help.

EDIT: EXAMPLE CODE
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64063159/ThesisTemplate.zip

Comment: By wrong do you mean that you would prefer to have the chapter name as _Appendix A_? In that case, would you also want the chapters in the main text to be named _Chapter 1_ instead of _1_? Also, it would be better to provide the code you used; I tried to compile a similar example, and the ToC shows _A Test_, instead of _Appendix A Test_.

Comment: 1. Yes, I would like to have it as Appendix A.
2. No, I like the chapter as they are, with just the number.
3. I added the \usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix} and wrote the appendix1.tex as 
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Test}
\end{appendices}

.I uploaded the code in the first post.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, using the chapter style of this template, displaying the chapter name in the appendices will look rather huge (in my opinion).
One alternative that you may or may not want to consider is to leave things as they are and load the appendix package with the `page` option. This will add a title (*Appendices* by default) at the point where the `appendices` environment begins.

If you want to go ahead, replace the chapter heading style in the settings.tex file with the following code.

```
% Chapter headings style (fncychap)
\makeatletter
\ChNumVar{} % sets the style for digit
\ChTitleVar{\Huge\bfseries\centering} % sets the style for title
\ChRuleWidth{4pt} % Set RW=4pt
\ChNameUpperCase % Make name uppercase
\renewcommand{\DOCH}{
\centering
\expandafter\ifx\@chapapp\appendixname
{\CNoV {\fontsize{60pt}{20pt}\selectfont\@chapapp\ \thechapter} }
\else
{\CNoV {\fontsize{60pt}{20pt}\selectfont\thechapter} }
\fi
\vskip 40\p@}
\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@}
\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you Pedro! I replaced the code and it worked, but as you said it is rather big. I wish I could set the appendix title like a "normal" chapter title font, for example like bibliography, content or Introduction. If you have some suggestions, please let me know. Anyway thank you again. I wish you the best! ;)

Comment: You could for instance replace the line `{\CNoV {\fontsize{60pt}{20pt}\selectfont\@chapapp\ \thechapter} }` with `\CTV\FmTi{\@chapapp\ \thechapter}\par\nobreak`. But then you may need to adjust the vertical spacings. I would recommend for you to try understanding everything that is happening in the chapter style definition, so that you can tweak it according to your personal preference.

Comment: PERFECT!!! Pedro, actually I do understand the code, but only after that you have written it. I'm a newbie in LaTeX and I'm still in the phase in which I can read the code but I can't  make important changes. Thanks again. Have a good one.